# iOS TableView (Bug: two scroll Bars Found As Zoomed)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am using TableView in my app. But as I zoom to highest available screen resolution. There I found two horizontal scrollbars. One vertical scrollbar is from the table view. I think next one is from the Default from iOS. I need to disable another except table view. Can I do this?
As i keep on Scrolling i can find two scroll Bars.I need to disable this ScrollBar since this is not of UIScroll View.

[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots or code

Comment: As a code i Have code of UITable View tat automatically have Scroll View.So i think adding the code of Table View Doesnot Give the sense.OK i will add my screenshot

Comment: OK i Have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Its just the simulator window scroll bar. You will not see it on the device. Second scroll bar indicates scrolling for the simulator window and it appears only when the simulator window extends beyond the mac screen.

Comment: oh!Thank you.I was a a bit confused.What to do.. :) :)